# how to set google map zooming lever correspond to address details

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a web form where the users can enter the parts of the address - country, region, zip, city, street, number, etc. I need to display that address on a google map. My problem is how to make google map zoom in according to the details of the address - the more information the user provides the more zoomed in is the map. For example, when the user has chosen only the country, the map is zoomed to country level. When the street is provided, the map is zoomed to street level.

Here is how I set the zoom level now:

```
        function UpdateAddressOnMap(sender, args) {
            var address = "";
            var zoom = 6;

            if ($("[id*='ddlCountry'] :selected").val() > 0)
                address = $("[id*='ddlCountry'] :selected").text();

            if ($("[id*='ddlRegion'] :selected").val() > 0)
                address += ", " + $("[id*='ddlRegion'] :selected").text();

            if ($("[id*='ddlDepartment'] :selected").val() > 0)
                address += ", " + $("[id*='ddlDepartment'] :selected").text();
            alert($("[id*='tbPostalCode']").val());
            if ($("[id*='tbPostalCode']").val().length > 0) {
                address += ", " + $("[id*='tbPostalCode']").val();
                zoom += 2;
            }

            if ($("[id*='tbCity']").val().length > 0) {
                address += ", " + $("[id*='tbCity']").val();
                zoom += 1;
            }

            if ($("[id*='tbNeighbourgood']").val().length > 0) {
                address += ", " + $("[id*='tbNeighbourgood']").val();
            }

            if ($("[id*='tbStreet']").val().length > 0) {
                address += ", " + $("[id*='tbStreet']").val();
                zoom += 2;
            }
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                    clearMarkers();
                    showFullAddressesOnMap(latitude, longitude, address)
                    map.setZoom(zoom);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I added some code but unfortunetly the website cannot be accesses publially

Comment: Using the free API requires the map to be public. Even if it's still being developed, if it's going to public sometime you may as well make it public now to assist. However, the first answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the `bounds` or the `viewport` objects returned by the Google Maps API Geocoder.Geometry object:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderGeometry

Comment: Both `viewport` and `bounds` return the same rectangle. In my case, the zoom level after `fitBounds` does not look nice, if "house number" level (i.e. location_type == "ROOFTOP") is returned. I can't see the better option other than using some "switch-case" construction and setting zoom level manually depending on `location_type`...